# Invalid configuration argument for Release configuration stand alone execution on x64 platform

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, cuda, release

I'm using:
GeForce GTX 1080 TI which has a compute capability 6.1.
OpenCV 3.2 version (was built for VS2013, x64 Release and Debug configurations separately).
CUDA 8.0 version.
Visual studio 2013, Relase and Debug configurations of x64 platform.

My purpose is to process part of the entire input image.
The image part declared by upper left coordinate and width and height.

Problem description:
An **invalid configuration argument** CUDA error is rasied **only** when I'm running the Release output in stand alone mode (without debugging) via visual studio DEBUG menu (**Ctrl + F5**).

If I'm running the same Release executable via VS Debug menu (F5) the error isn't raised.

Also, when I'm running the output of Debug configuration that was generated by the same application code, both options F5 and Ctrl+F5 are work properly and the error isn't raised.

Here is my code:

```
struct sRect
{
unsigned int m_StartRow;
unsigned int m_StartCol;
unsigned int m_SizeRows;
unsigned int m_SizeCols;
};
__global__ void CleanNoisePreparation(unsigned char * SrcImage, size_t     iStep, const sRect ImageSlice)
{
int iXPos = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
int iYPos = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;

if (!(iXPos < ImageSlice.m_SizeCols && iYPos < ImageSlice.m_SizeRows))
    return;

/*In case pixel value is less or equal to 127 set it to black color (0) otherwisw set it to white color (255)*/
SrcImage[iYPos * iStep + iXPos] = (SrcImage[iYPos * iStep + iXPos] <= (unsigned char)127) ? ((unsigned char)0) : ((unsigned char)255);
}
void PerformCleanNoisePreparationOnGPU(cv::cuda::GpuMat& Image,
                                    const sRect &ImageSlice,
                                    const dim3 &dimGrid,
                                    const dim3 &dimBlock,
                                    const cudaStream_t &Stream)
{
      /*Calculate the rquired start address based on the required image slice characteristics*/

unsigned char * pImageData = (unsigned char*)(Image.data ImageSlice.m_StartRow * Image.step + ImageSlice.m_StartCol);

CleanNoisePreparation << <dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, Stream >> >(pImageData, Image.step, ImageSlice);
CUDA(cudaGetLastError());
}

void main
{
    sRect ResSliceParams;        

    ResSliceParams.m_StartRow = 0;
ResSliceParams.m_StartCol = 4854;
ResSliceParams.m_SizeRows = 7096;
ResSliceParams.m_SizeCols = 5146;
    cv::cuda::GpuMat MyFrame = cv::cuda::GpuMat::GpuMat(cv::Size(10000, 7096), CV_8U);
    //Image step size is 10240

    dim3 dimBlock (32, 32, 1)
    dim3 dimGrid (161, 222, 1)

    cudaStream_t cudaStream;

    cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&cudaStream, cudaStreamNonBlocking);

    PerformCleanNoisePreparationOnGPU(MyFrame,
                                            ResSliceParams,
                                            dimGrid,
                                            dimBlock,
                                            cudaStream);
}
```

The error is raised also when:

1. The kernel is totally empty (All lines were commented)
2. The kernel inputs list is empty.
3. Default stream is used instead of specific stream

Comment: What architecture are you compiling for? Your GPU is a compute capability 6.1 device, not 3.0. The CUDA 8 toolkit will default to compute 2.0. That might explain the launch failure.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
You are right about the CC, it was a typo.
Regarding to your question about the architecture:
If I'm understanding you correctly I'm using Release configuration and x64 Platform. If not please clarify.
Can you guide me please how can I change the CC for the CUDA 8.0 toolkit?

Comment: If it's a typo, then [edit] the question and fix it.

Comment: No problem, I fixed it.

Comment: I changed the CUDA compute capability via the Visual Studio menu:
Project->Properties->CUDA C/C++->Device-> Code Generation
to be: compute_61, sm_61.
The problem is still exist.
Additional information:
When I change the following the problem disappear:
ResSliceParams.m_StartRow = 0;
ResSliceParams.m_StartCol = 0;
ResSliceParams.m_SizeRows = 7096;
ResSliceParams.m_SizeCols = 10000;

Please advise.

Comment: I also made the following change:
dim3 dimGrid (313, 222, 1)
Before it start to work properly

Answer (score 1):

The problem source was found.
Due to the fact that the problem was raised only when I was executed my application under Release without debugging mode I could only used a prints commands in order to learn what are the variables values and what is the real flow of the code.

So, I was figured that dimGrid.y was set to a negative value by mistake only in this execution mode and under all other executions modes it was a positive value as I was expected.
Due to this negative value the CUDA was raised the rror of "Invalid configuration argument".

More detailes:
I have a code which calculate the required dimGrid values based on the input image resolution and if it is a portrait or a landscape.
I'm using a class member from type bool to hold this indication and send its initialization value to other sub classes as part of the member initialization list calls of the main class which include all of them as a members.

It was figured out that only in Release without debugging execution mode the bool value was false instead of true (which represents landscape mode) in the scope of the sub classes in opposite to its value in the scope of the main class.

I was verified that I it was initialized (as part of the member initialization list) to true before I sent it to all other sub classes constructors but due to the fact that class members initialization order isn't determined according to the members initialization list order but according to thier declarations order in the class it was sent to them an uninitiated.

In my system, only in Release without debugging execution mode, an uninitiated bool type get 0 value but in all other exections mode it get a positive value.

While "if" condition is performed on an uninitiated bool type, 0 translated to false but any positive value is translated to true.

This was caused to a wrong calculation of the dimGrid values.